In Docker: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cinema.movies' doesn't exist in
I tried to build a container for a PHP-apache app with MariaDB and PhpMyAdmin and i receive the error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cinema.movies' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/app/DAO/MovieDAO.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/app/DAO/MovieDAO.php(14): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/app/Controllers/MovieController.php(16): App\DAO\MovieDAO->getAllMovies() #2 /var/www/html/resources/Views/home.php(5): App\Controllers\MovieController->getAllMovies() #3 /var/www/html/index.php(67): include_once('/var/www/html/r...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/app/DAO/MovieDAO.php on line 14

and if i try to go to port 8081 (PMA) i receive the error that i dont have access.
I cannot understand why i dont have access to the db, or why seems like that the db doesnt exist.
My yml file is:
services:
  web:
    image: php:8.2.18-apache
    container_name: cinema
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: $(DB_HOST)
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $(DB_NAME)
      MYSQL_USER: $(DB_USER)
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $(DB_PASS)
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image:  mariadb:10.4.32
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: "1"
      MYSQL_HOST: $(DB_HOST)
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $(DB_NAME)
      MYSQL_USER: $(DB_USER)
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $(DB_PASS)
      MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: "1"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./cinema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/cinema.sql
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image:  phpmyadmin:5.2.1
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: $(DB_HOST)
      PMA_USER: $(DB_USER)
      PMA_PASSWORD: $(DB_PASS)
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  db_data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge


And the Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2.18-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN node -v && npm -v

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 composer install
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

I had that issue   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory and i solve it by adding the volume to the db image and changing the db host directly in the .env file
Please someone can help me?

container logs from the mariadb container would confirm initialization behaviour.

It looks like one of:
a) The MariaDB data volume was initialized before the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d got a entry to initialize the database with the missing table/view.
or:
b) you are accessing the web before MariaDB has completed initialization.
The solution for b) is:
services:
  web:
...
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
...
  db:
...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      start_period: 10s
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
...
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

Also, don't pass MYSQL_HOST to the MariaDB container. For the others its where to connect. For the MariaDB container is meaningless.
ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh/

I solved the issue with the option b, or better, i explain it: with this fix i ve been access to phpmyadmin, and i noticed that the db has been created, but empty, so i needed to import the sql file for to solve it. BTW thank you :)
